# How can I recover access to a Windows 10 virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-10, vmware, passwords

I have a Windows 10 virtual machine (host: VMware Fusion 7.1.2 on El Capitan), and I gave it a PIN on installation. I tried this morning to get into it, and it said on each of several tries that the machine was ?isolated? and couldn't confirm it, and asked me for a password. My password manager does have a password for "Windows 10", but the password appeared to be unrelated, and at any rate didn't work.

It has (and shows) my email address. Is there a way I can get a password/PIN reset so I can access my VM?

Comment: Enable the `Administrator`, user which is disabled by default, and use that user, to change the password of your current user.  Once logged into the user you can reset the Pin.

Comment: Note that you'd have the same problem with Windows 10 on a physical machine, so there's nothing virtualization-specific here. [ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) maybe could help, but I don't know if it works with the Windows 10 PIN thing.